# How to find source of a bootstrap-modal dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap modal and jquery.

How to find the source button, when there are more than one button from which modal dialog could be created ?

Before bootstrap-modal, I was using onclick to show confirm message, like, onclick="newGame(3, true)"; now I want to do it with bootstrap-modal.

html,

```
<button type="button" class="btn" id="ctrl6" data-controls-modal="my-modal" data- 
backdrop="static">3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="ctrl7" data-controls-modal="my-modal" data-
backdrop="static">4</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="ctrl8" data-controls-modal="my-modal" data- 
backdrop="static">5</button>

<div id="my-modal" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
...
</div>
```

js,

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      // Hide modal if "Go back" is pressed
      $('#my-modal .go-back-button').click(function() {
        $('#my-modal').modal('hide');
      });

      // Hide modal if "Okay" is pressed
      $('#my-modal .okay-button').click(function() {
        $('#my-modal').modal('hide');
      });
  });
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may find a recent pull request useful: [Allow passing data arguments to modal](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/4392#commits-pushed-37f294b)

This commit modifies the Modal plugin so that it grabs all the data attributes on the triggering element.  By adding unique identifiers in all the triggering elements, let's say `data-user="some_uid"`, that data can be retrieved from the modal object in the future.

For example, if the buttons in the example used:

```
<button data-user="4" ... >
<button data-user="5" ... >
<button data-user="6" ... >
```

In the callbacks you could access that info:

```
// Hide modal if "Okay" is pressed
$('#my-modal').on('click', '.okay-button', function(e) {
  var modal = $(e.delegateTarget).data('modal');

  console.log('Originating element user: ' + modal.options.user);

  modal.hide();
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/Crmhe/)

<sub>**Note**: I realize the API for the modal has changed significantly since this question was asked, which is partly why I glossed over the other details of the button markup.  However, I think the problem to be solved is still relevant.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function accepts a parameter that links to the element triggering the event:

```
$('#my-modal .okay-button').click(function(e) {
   // e is the element that triggered the event
   console.log(e.target); // outputs an Object that you can then explore with Firebug/developer tool.
   // for example e.target.firstChild.wholeText returns the text of the button
});
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/naoise/CLxkS/) (jsfiddle).

Comment: Here 'e' is an event from, ok/cancel anchor element.

May be my question is not clear. I am tryinng to find out from which button (ctrl6, ctrl7, etc.) modal dialog was created. I want these details in modal ok/cancel handlers.

Comment: @vi.su. `e` is a direct "link" to the button. see this example http://jsfiddle.net/naoise/CLxkS/

Comment: thanks for your response. I am not able to find a solution for this issue, so I am now going to move all the 'ctrlxx' buttons to modal, leaving only one button in the page. :-)